# System is automatically sending large numbers of emails

Tags: email

My desktop server (which has WAMP installed) is sending a large amount of messages to an unknown email addresses like 
some@some.ru or .fr and blah blah blah...

I installed Symantec AV and it's regularly popping up a message like:

> Your email message to camilarodriguz2@example.com.br with the subject of visitor off was unable to be sent [...]

What's going on?

Comment: what is the role of your 'system'?  Mail server, web server desktop, other?

Comment: desktop server and i have installed wamp on it

Comment: Sounds like you've been hacked to bits. Time to reinstall the operating system.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a server, make sure you don't have an SMTP service running.  If so, check the access rules on it and also turn off remote forwarding or just disable it entirely if uneeded.  Don't forget to check the Windows SMTP server that comes with IIS as well.

If no SMTP services are running, then you likely have either a virus or spyware.

Install Spybot Search and Destory, Windows Defender, and/or AdAware.
Update the virus definitions on Symantec and the spyware definitions on whatever software you installed.
Uplug from the Internet.
Reboot into safe mode.
Do a full scan for viruses first, then for spyware.
Plug back in.
Reboot.

Install and run HiJack this and remove anything that should be there.